# Evaluating $\int_{1}^{\infty}\ \frac{\sqrt[3]{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^3+3}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, indefinite-integrals

I tried doing :

$\int_{1}^{\infty}\ \frac{\sqrt[3]{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^3+3}}dx \approx \int_{1}^{\infty}\ \frac{x^\frac{1}{3}}{x^\frac{3}{2}}dx  =  \int_{1}^{\infty}\ \frac{1}{x^\frac{7}{6}}dx $

*According to the  **P test** for improper integrals* , we get :

$ \frac{7}{6} >1$

$\Longrightarrow $ The Integral $converges$  .

I'm not sure if my solution is valid and works , However according to an online computing website the integral does in fact $converge$.

**I Would like to know if there is another way to solve this integral and if my math works !**

*Thanks in Advance !*

Comment: I would approach this initially via seeing if $x^3+3$ can be factorised (real or complex), then splitting it into partial fractions

Comment: Do you wish to evaluate it or to check its convergence?

Comment: In fact, what you properly wrote (but without concluding - try to do it) is that
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^3+3}} < \frac{1}{x^{7/6}}$$ which makes that
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt[3]{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^3+3}}\,dx <6$$

Comment: When I try to integrate it computationally, I get the concrete form involving the [Gamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) and [Generalized Hypergeometric Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html): $$\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{18}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{18}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{13}{18}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{4}{3}\right) \, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{18},\frac{7}{18},\frac{13}{18};\frac{5}{6},\frac{7}{6};-3\right)}{\sqrt[3]{3} \pi ^{3/2}}$$ (But I am not sure if this helps - if so I can try to expand this into an answer.)

Comment: I only need to check if it converges !